# regex that matches the text between the tags like p a, br

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need a regex that matches the text between the tags like p a, br:
Albert Einstein, Division Head, Princeton
Member of the Executive Committee of Princeton

I have a pattern for (Preg_match_all)

`$pattern="/<\s*a[^>]++>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*a\s*>/"`;

but it gives me only the text inside a hrefs,

any hints? thanks
// Heres the Sample Source

```
<p>
    <a href="file.pdf" target="_blank"><b>Albert Einstein</b></a><br>
    Division Head, Princeton<br>
    Member of the Executive Committee of Princeton<br>
    </p>
```

Comment: Try using an HTML parser instead. See [this answer on a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579)

Comment: use a dom parser, its easy on your php

Comment: Use a DOM parser to load the HTML, initialize an XPath object, and do `foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $node) { echo $node->nodeValue.PHP_EOL; }`

Answer (score 0):

using a dom parser you can get the values inside tags you want :

```
<?php
$html='<p>
    <a href="file.pdf" target="_blank"><b>Albert Einstein</b></a><br>
    Division Head, Princeton<br>
    Member of the Executive Committee of Princeton<br>
    </p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo "[".$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue."]";
```

you can change the tag value and see .

demo here : https://eval.in/139559

just changing the value from `p` to `b`, you can get the text inside `b` tag , i.e. `[Albert Einstein]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML parser. If you really want a regex you can use this:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<p>
    <a href="file.pdf" target="_blank"><b>Albert Einstein</b></a><br>
     Division Head, Princeton<br>
 Member of the Executive Committee of Princeton<br>
    </p>
EOF;

preg_match_all('%(?:\s+|<b>)([\w ]+)(?:</b>|<br>)%m', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i++) {
    echo $result[1][$i]."\n";
}

/*
Albert Einstein
Princeton
Member of the Executive Committee of Princeton
*/
```

http://ideone.com/x8aZdd